# Jenkins Unable to Match Two Identical Strings

Tags: jenkins, yaml, groovy

I have a config file that's in YAML format, which includes this relevant portion:

```
project:
  protectedBranches:
    - master
    - develop
    - feature/something
```

In my Jenkinsfile, the YAML file is loaded via: `config = readYaml('config.yml')`.

I also have `env.GIT_BRANCH = env.gitlabSourceBranch` which results in `env.GIT_BRANCH` containing the value `origin/feature/something`

The `config.project.protectedBranches` is of type `ArrayList()`

I am attempting to do something based on whether `env.GIT_BRANCH` exists in the `config.project.protectedBranches`, but none of the following have worked.

```
def shortBranch = env.GIT_BRANCH
shortBranch = shortBranch.minus("origin/")
// shortBranch now has a value of feature/something

if(shortBranch in config.project.protectedBranches) // returns false
```

Also...

```
config.project.protectedBranches.each{ branch ->
    echo "Does branch match shortBranch? ${branch.equals(shortBranch)}" // returns false
    echo "Does branch match shortBranch? ${branch == shortBranch}" // also returns false
}
```

Both `branch` and `shortBranch` are of type `String`. Why on Earth can I not compare these strings?

The issue only occurs when the `branch` string contains a forward-slash, e.g, `feature/something`. Additionally, someone asked if I've verified the type of each, and yes I have. Both `shortBrancg.getClass()` and `branch.getClass()` return type `java.lang.String`.

Comment: The second example may be falling prey to how Groovy works in Jenkinsfiles. the `.each` may only 'run' on the last element in the list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47027926/2196304 Maybe try it with a simple for loop.

Comment: Have you done some basic debugging?  E.g. `echo "Comparing branch '${branch}' with shortBranch '${shortBranch}'"` to verify that you're comparing the values you expect you're comparing

Comment: @jayhendren Yes I did some debugging. Both `shortBranch.getClass()` and `branch.getClass()` return `java.lang.String`. Furthermore, it turns out it's something to do with the `\` in the branch name because it works as intended for `develop` and `master` branches.

Comment: @KymikoLoco Just to clarify, the `.each` works, it's the comparison within that is not working.

Comment: Stands to reason that the strings you are comparing are not equal, then? What is the output of the strings you are comparing (not just the class, not just the comparison itself, but the actual strings like @jayhendren suggests)? You've not shown what those values are. Also, depending on what you are running and when, in Pipelines GIT_BRANCH will be set when Jenkins checks out code. That may be overwriting your env.GIT_BRANCH, but it's hard to tell without https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario in the script console using the snakeyaml classes also used by the utility step, and couldn't. My guess is (because of some copy&paste?) you have got some non-printable characters in your yaml config file, like for instance a zero width space. To check, use: `println ${branch.getBytes()}`

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Looks like you're on to something. `branch` and `shortBranch`, are NOT the same in bytes. `branch bytes: [102, 101, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 47, 106, 101, 110, 107, 105, 110, 115, 45, 98, 117, 105, 108, 100, 45, 100, 111, 99, 107, -30, -128, -117, 101, 114]` and `shortBranch bytes: [102, 101, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 47, 106, 101, 110, 107, 105, 110, 115, 45, 98, 117, 105, 108, 100, 45, 100, 111, 99, 107, 101, 114]`. I can't for the life of me understand why these are different. Is is something related to encoding perhaps? The git server is Gitlab if that is matters.

Comment: yes, as you can see you have not printable characters (if you try to convert the first array back to string you'll see "?" characters in `feature/jenkins-build-dock???er` at the position of -30, -128, -117 (which are &#226, &#128 and &#139).

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Thanks for your help with this. I assume this occurred when copying/pasting the YAML from my IDE to Gitlab. The fix was simple, just delete the value and re-type it. If you'd like to submit the above as an answer, I'll mark it as answered so you get the proper credit.

Comment: You are welcome, anyway I prefer to vote to close the topic as a typographical error since it won't likely be helpful to others